# How is spark a memory based solution if it writes data to disk before shuffles?

Tags: apache-spark, mapreduce

One of the main "selling points" of Spark is that unlike Hadoop map-reduce that persists intermediate results of its computation to hdfs, Spark keeps all its results in memory. I don't understand this as in reality when a Spark stage finishes [it writes all of the data into shuffle files stored on the disk](https://github.com/JerryLead/SparkInternals/blob/master/markdown/english/4-shuffleDetails.md). How then is this an improvement on map-reduce?

[image: Image taken from Advanced Apache Spark Training - Sameer Farooqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand where Spark saves IO.

in MR the computation looks like:

```
map -> reduce -> map -> reduce -> map -> reduce ...
```

which writes results to disk at each such "arrow",

on the other hand in spark we have

```
map -> reduce + map -> reduce + map -> reduce ...
```

which saves about 2 times the IO